How to use api route in nextron or is there any other solution?
I wrote a desktop application using nextron (nextjs+electron) (using nextjs' api route, which is ssr), but when packaging, I was told that nextron only supports next's api route (ssr) in development mode, but not in production mode. Using it, I can only use the next spa mode, and then my application can only stay in the development mode. I want to know what should I do? I don't want to give up ssr in nextjs because I think this is a very important feature in nextjs.
I tried many electron templates on github that said they support SSR, but none of them worked. Although these templates allowed me to successfully export in a non-static manner, they failed on the login interface because next-auth could not connect normally.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
